# Add NOT NULL LOB column without default in Oracle

Tags: oracle

I am trying to add a CLOB column to a table (change a VARCHAR to a CLOB actually, but it only seems possible by adding a new column, copying and dropping the old). The column should be NOT NULL without a default value (and the table is not empty). How can I achieve this?

My original idea was to create the column with a dummy default, and change that later, but that does not seem possible:

```
ALTER TABLE foo RENAME COLUMN text TO text_temp;
ALTER TABLE foo ADD (
    text CLOB DEFAULT '*' NOT NULL
);
UPDATE foo SET text = text_temp;
ALTER TABLE foo DROP COLUMN text_temp;
ALTER TABLE foo MODIFY (
    text CLOB NOT NULL
);
-- ORA-22296: invalid ALTER TABLE option for conversion of LONG datatype to LOB
```

I also tried defining the column as `text CLOB` and adding the NOT NULL constraint later, but it gave the same error. Is there a way of doing this, short of recreating the whole table?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Does

```
ALTER TABLE foo MODIFY text DEFAULT NULL;
```

work for you?

When adding or removing a default value or a NOT NULL constraint, you don't need to specify the datatype of the column.

**EDIT**: To quote the [Oracle documentation on `ALTER TABLE`](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/statements_3001.htm#sthref5073):

> If a column has a default value, then you can use the DEFAULT clause to change the default to NULL, but you cannot remove the default value completely. If a column has ever had a default value assigned to it, then the DATA_DEFAULT column of the USER_TAB_COLUMNS data dictionary view will always display either a default value or NULL.

This should explain why you're seeing a difference in SQL Developer.

However, I don't believe there's a significant difference between specifying `DEFAULT NULL` for a column and not specifying a default value.  In both cases, a null value will be assumed for any column not explicitly given a value in an `INSERT` statement.

Comment: That works indeed, but it leaves the default value as NULL, which is not the same as no value (SQL Developer shows `NULL` in the first case, and `(null)` in the second). Is the difference insignificant?

Answer (score 3):

You are declaring the column as NOT NULL when you added it to the table, so you don't need to make it NOT NULL again.  I think if you corrected the syntax in the final MODIFY clause you would still get an error, albeit a different one (precise number eludes me right now).

But what you are trying to acheive is definitely possible, with the right syntax :)

```
SQL> alter table t23 add ctxt clob
  2  /

Table altered.

SQL> update t23 set ctxt = txt
  2  /

2 rows updated.

SQL> alter table t23 modify ctxt not null
  2  /

Table altered.

SQL> alter table t23 drop column txt
  2  /

Table altered.

SQL> alter table t23 rename column ctxt to txt
  2  /

Table altered.

SQL>
```